# Sync single table between MSSQL and MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, synchronization

I need to synchronize a table between our MSSQL Database to our MySQL Database.

The MSSQL Datbase is the master, MySQL the clone.

I can not link the tables(thats the solution when you google it), i have to do it with Queries and a Cronjob.

I first thought of:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table;
```

And compare both but this does not detect changes in rows.

How is the best way to check for changes and new Data?

Comment: Solution: with difficulty!

Comment: More seriously: you'll have to modify your MSSQL DB design to include a `timestamp` column (ignore the name, it's more like a serial number) to provide versioning information.

Comment: Sounds like a common approach for theese requirements.

Comment: Check this site http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2009/02/25/howto-setup-sql-server-linked-server-to-mysql/

Comment: you could add some more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could MD5-hash the selected result and compare the hashstrings:

```
SELECT MD5( GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT_WS('#',id,name,password) SEPARATOR '##' ) ) FROM table
```